# "querySnapshot.forEach" is not working in firebase cloud function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm calling a function of firestore on create triggers that adds the data to a collection from another collection, but the problem is when I store the data in querysnapshot variable but function can't iterate querysnapshot, It doesn't even go inside the querysnapshot.forEach. When I tested locally it worked but it doesn't on the server. I really am stuck here. If anyone can be a helping hand, please reply

EDIT

I have data in userPosts collection but I'm not getting any document in querysnapshot, it's returning 0 docs, I don't understand why though?

I have attached my console result as well as Firestore data and updated the code.

[Firebase function Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xHpm.png)

[Firestore data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tvD4.png)

[Firestore data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzwlw.png)

[Firestore data 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4YBh.png)

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);

export const onCreateFollower = functions.firestore
    .document("/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{followerId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
         console.log("Follower Created", snapshot.id);
        const userId = context.params.userId;

        console.log("User ID", userId);

        const followerId = context.params.followerId;

        console.log("Follower ID", followerId);

        // 1) Create followed users posts ref
        const followedUserPostsRef = firestore
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("userPosts");

        // 2) Create following user's timeline ref
        const timelinePostsRef = firestore
            .collection("timeline")
            .doc(followerId)
            .collection("timelinePosts");

        // 3) Get followed users posts
        followedUserPostsRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
            console.log(`Inside QuerySnapshot with ${querySnapshot.size} docs`)
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log("Inside ForEach");
                if (doc.exists) {
                    const postId = doc.id;
                    console.log(postId)
                    const postData = doc.data();
                    console.log(postData) //Q2g2EutTRSOr9GPmeBlkt0ZZ40m2
                    timelinePostsRef.doc(postId).set(postData).then(() => {
                        console.log("Data successfully Added.")
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        console.log("Could not set the Data");
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            });
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

log of Querysnapshot

```
QuerySnapshot {
  _query: 
   CollectionReference {
     _firestore: 
      Firestore {
        _settings: [Object],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _serializer: [Object],
        _projectId: 'test',
        registeredListenersCount: 0,
        bulkWritersCount: 0,
        _backoffSettings: [Object],
        _clientPool: [Object] },
     _queryOptions: 
      QueryOptions {
        parentPath: [Object],
        collectionId: 'userPosts',
        converter: [Object],
        allDescendants: false,
        fieldFilters: [],
        fieldOrders: [],
        startAt: undefined,
        endAt: undefined,
        limit: undefined,
        limitType: undefined,
        offset: undefined,
        projection: undefined },
     _serializer: 
      Serializer {
        createReference: [Function],
        createInteger: [Function],
        allowUndefined: false },
     _allowUndefined: false },
  _readTime: undefined,
  _size: 0,
  _materializedDocs: null,
  _materializedChanges: null,
  _docs: [Function],
  _changes: [Function] }
```

Comment: Do you see any error (from the `console.log()` in the `catch` block)? Also how do you define `firestore`? Can you share your entire `index.js` file? Are you sure there are documents in the collection? What is the size of the querySnapshot? Finally, note that you are not returning the Promises returned by the asynchronous Firebase methods. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions as this is a key point.

Comment: If `querySnapshot.forEach` doesn't iterate anything, that means your query returned no documents.  Since we can't see your data or any of the variables you're using here, we can't tell why you are getting an empty result set.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec  thank you for replying. 
I have updated the question please take a look.

Comment: @DougStevenson  thank you for replying. I have updated the question please take a look

Comment: could you log the `querySnapshot` ?

Comment: @JoséSoní I've updated the code please take a look.

Comment: I've solved the problem. Thank you all. problem was firebase function package version.

Comment: Could you share your answer, Iĺl be happy to upvote

Comment: @JoséSoní I was using firsebase-admin@9.0.0 with Node 8 environment, everything was working fine but I just couldn't get the data out of firestore which was confusing. Finally, I read the release notes of firebase-admin package which stated that

"the Admin SDK now requires Node.js 10 or higher. Node.js 8 support has been discontinued."


And that was the problem.


  [1]: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node